# Como recuperar um valor anterior digitado pelo usuário?

Tags: java

Não estou conseguindo recuperar um valor digitado antes pelo usuário.

O programa pede para entrar com notas e o final ser indicado pela entrada do numero -1;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        ArrayList<Integer> notas = new ArrayList<>();

        System.out.println("Entre com notas de 0 a 10");
        int num = 0; // criei essa variavel para fazer as instruçoes ficarem em loop ate o usuario digitar o -1 

        while(num != -1){ 

            notas.add(s.nextInt()); //aqui armazena o primeiro valor digitado

            if(s.nextInt() == -1){ // nesta linha eu sei que que esta pegando o segundo valor digitado e se caso ele seja -1, atribuo o valor -1 a num, saindo assim do loop
                num = -1;
            }else{ //caso o valor nao seja -1 vai adicionar no ArrayList
                notas.add(s.nextInt()); //aqui esta o problema, eu nao consigo adicionar o valor anterior que foi comparado no if
                }
        }

        System.out.println(notas.toString());

    }
```

Comment: Nao estou conseguindo recuperar um valor digitado antes, entende. Por exemplo: Digitei a nota 1, ela esta sendo armazenada, quando estou digitando a nota 2 ela esta sendo comparada no if com -1. Como ela nao é igual eu vou para o else, porem nao esta armazenando a nota 2 e sim a proxima nota. Mais ou menos isso. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma solução pode ser esta:

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        var s = new Scanner(System.in);
        var notas = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        System.out.println("Entre com notas de 0 a 10");
        var num = 0;
        while (num != -1) { 
            num = s.nextInt(); //armazena em variável para poder usar onde quiser
            if (num != -1) notas.add(num);
        }
        System.out.println(notas.toString());
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/h1rArv). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/cfbjdutf-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/Grades.java).

A principal função de uma variável é armazenar um valor para uso posterior. Economizar variável é bom, mas quando ela é necessária, tem que criar e armazenar o valor que deseja usa depois. Assim resolve a principal questão a pergunta. Mas na verdade a variável já criada pode ser aproveitada para isto e nem criar uma extra. Além disto seu código não faz o que você espera, por isso eu mudei a lógica.

Comment: Vou testar aqui amigo. Ja volto para falar do resultado. Muito obrigado.

Comment: @MatheusGuedes dei uma melhorada nele. Neste caso era mais fácil fazer como está agora. E não introduz um comando que talvez você nem tenha aprendido ainda.

Comment: Muito bom amigo. Deu muito certo.

Answer (score 0):

Só fazer assim:

```
int temp = s.nextInt();
if(temp == -1){
   num = -1;
}else{ //caso o valor nao seja -1 vai adicionar no ArrayList
  notas.add(temp); //pega o ultimo valor digitado
}
```

Comment: Vou testar aqui e volto para falar. Muito obrigado.